# How to create a GDataXMLDocument with GDataXML parser

Tags: ios

I need to parse an XML file using GDataXML, as long as i have also to rewrite it. 
The problem i met is not about how to do this, there are tons of tutorials and i think i got the procedure.
Basically there's some line of code i can't make it work:

```
+(ArrayItems *)loadXML{ 

NSLog(@"Start");

NSString *filePath=[ArrayItemsParser dataFilePath];
if (filePath!=nil) NSLog(@"Filepath created: %@",filePath);

NSData *xmlData=[NSMutableData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
if(xmlData!=nil) NSLog(@"xmlData created");

NSError *error;
GDataXMLDocument *docXML=[[GDataXMLDocument alloc] initWithData:xmlData error:&error];
if(docXML!=nil) NSLog(@"Done");

NSLog(@"End");
```

This is the beginning of a static method i use to load the informations i need from the XML file into the class models i created.
Basically when i run the project to check what it's not working, it's gonna print only "Start" on the console.
But if i remove from code the lines

```
NSError *error;
GDataXMLDocument *docXML=[[GDataXMLDocument alloc] initWithData:xmlData error:&error];
if(docXML!=nil) NSLog(@"Done");
```

and run again the project, this time it's gonna print on console

2012-09-27 11:39:46.617 ParsingMap2[11388:207] Start

2012-09-27 11:39:46.619 ParsingMap2[11388:207] Filepath created: /Users/ivanmelis/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/CD93660C-
46FB-4118-9A8D-0574433F6BAB/ParsingMap2.app/ConfMap.xml

2012-09-27 11:39:46.619 ParsingMap2[11388:207] xmlData created

2012-09-27 11:39:46.619 ParsingMap2[11388:207] End

So i suppose the problem is in the lines

```
NSError *error;
GDataXMLDocument *docXML=[[GDataXMLDocument alloc] initWithData:xmlData error:&error];
if(docXML!=nil) NSLog(@"Done");
```

As i mentioned i read some tutorials and the GDataXML parser's documentation, but i couldn't solve the problem...or at least i can't see how to fix it. It seems that's the right way to do create an GDatatXMLDocument.
Does anyone can give me an advice?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! +1 for well-written question. Good luck!